# Why does `function == &function`?

Tags: c, callback, reference, function-pointers, dereference

I've always done `callback = functionpointer`, but found `callback = &functionpointer` in [some code](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/6b9c2fca79a7b77a42242d48b0cfa82d612e9b85/examples/protocols/https_request/main/https_request_example_main.c#L317) recently and thought it was strange, expecting that `&functionpointer` would effectively give a double-pointer.

So I tried this example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int i)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

int main()
{
    void (*g)(int) = f;  // without &
    void (*h)(int) = &f; // _with_ &

    printf("g=%p\n", g);
    printf("h=%p\n", h);
    g(1);
    h(2);
}
```

which prints this:

```
g=0x401126
h=0x401126
1
2
```

I was surprised that it didn't crash, and equally surprised that `f == &f` (which is, of course, why it didn't crash).

What is the deal here?  Is this just C spec, or some other nuanced "feature" (that I'd like to learn more about)?

Comment: The behavior you observed is dictated by the language spec.

Comment: same as arrays. Both decay to pointers

Comment: The cool thing. Given: `void foo(void); void (*bar)(void) = foo;` Further down we can do: `foo(); bar();` Six months from now, if the author changes `foo` to: `void baz(void); void (*foo)(void) = baz; void (*bar)(void) = foo;`, the caller's code (`foo(); bar();`) will still work _unchanged_.

Comment: You actually meant `function == &function`. This would not work if you used it on a function pointer. `h == &h` won't be the same in your code.